# Задача на нахождения максимума из последовательности

Tags: алгоритм

Написать программу с использованием хранения последовательности чисел в памяти компьютера (количество чисел в последовательности считать известным). Использовать оператор `for`. Даны действительные числа `a1, ... a30`. Получить: `max (a1 + a30, a2 + a29, ..., a15 + a16)`

Comment: Причем метка СЕРВЕР ?
Какой язык программирования?

Comment: Ответ в комментариях к ответу, данному @Dem. В **max** поместите **a1+a30**. В цикле идите от **a2** к середине, вычисляя сумму "крайних".

Answer (score 1):

Это очень просто. Создайте массив из 15 элементов b, а затем цикл от 1 до 15, `b[i] = a [i] + a [30-i + 1]`. Далее необходимо найти максимум в b.

Answer (score 0):

```
max = -1;
for(i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    if(arr[i] > max){
        max = arr[i];
    }
}
```

Логика такая, а дальше переделывать под нужный язык.

Comment: Лучше max=arr[0]; for (i = 1;....

Comment: Не принципиально, суть не меняется

Comment: Принципиально, т.к. в вопросе **действительные числа**